# How to get content-desc attribute of an element in android using appium with ruby

Tags: android, ruby, appium

I am trying to fetch content-desc attribute of an element using

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Automation']").attribute("content-desc")
```

but getting this error

> [debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getAttribute() with args:
> ["xpath","19","f0ea41e6-dfee-4b9b-b756-0b204863d0d4"]
>
> [debug][AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android:
> {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getAttribute","params":{"attribute":"content-desc","elementId":"19"}}
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
> {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getAttribute","params":{"attribute":"content-desc","elementId":"19"}}
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action:
> getAttribute
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning
> result: {"status":7,"value":"This element does not have the
> 'content-desc' attribute"}

I have checked with appium UI that content-desc attribute exists, is there anything wrong in my code? Is there any alternate to it?

Comment: I believe your code is correct the possible mistake could be the incorrect xpath or the attribute name so I suggest to use `contentDescription` instead of content-desc. if not works then try with other locators

Answer (score 1):

Try to use getAttribute("contentDescription")

Answer (score 0):

In python (I guess with Ruby will be similar) I do it like this:

**Python code**

```
webElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Automation']")
content-desc = webElement.get_attribute("content-desc")
print(content-desc)
```

This webElement.get_attribute(attr) is applicable to @text, @checked, @enabled, @selected, @name, @value......

But anyway... you posted this message where the element was not found:

> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"This element does not have the 'content-desc' attribute"}

So maybe your XPATH is not correct and you are selecting a wrong element...
If this doesn't work for you, you will have to post an image of Appium Inspector to be able to help you